# Multi-Column check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-server

Consider a simple table..

```
create table dbo.car(    car_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER default(newid()) 
                      ,  car_type varchar(20) not null
                      ,  wind_protector varchar(20) not null
)

insert into dbo.car(car_type, wind_protector) VALUES('HARD_TOP', 'NA')
insert into dbo.car(car_type, wind_protector) VALUES('CONVERTIBLE', 'FLAPBLAST_3')
insert into dbo.car(car_type, wind_protector) values('CONVERTIBLE', 'FLAPBLAST_2')
```

I'm trying to craft a check constraint that says if car_type is "CONVERTIBLE" then wind_protector can be "FLAPBLAST_2" or "FLAPBLAST_3". Otherwise the value of wind_protector is "NA". The column can not be null.

I have the basic check constraint written..

```
([wind_protector]='FLAPBLAST_3' OR [wind_protector]='FLAPBLAST_3')
```

I'm stuck on writing the check constraint across two columns and using and or logic.

Is it possible to do what I'm looking to accomplish?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the following constraint:

```
alter table car 
add constraint chk1 
check (
  ( car_type='CONVERTIBLE' and wind_protector in ('FLAPBLAST_2','FLAPBLAST_3')) 
    or wind_protector='NA' 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple multi-column constraint with `AND` `OR` logic

```sql
CHECK (
    car_type = 'CONVERTIBLE' AND wind_protector IN ('FLAPBLAST_2', 'FLAPBLAST_3')
    OR
    car_type = 'CONVERTIBLE' AND wind_protector = 'NA'
)
```

**But you don't want a `check` constraint here.** `wind_protector` is not a property of `Car`, it is a property of `CarType`. And it can have multiple `wind_protector`.

So you need to normalize your schema into proper Third Normal Form. You need a few more tables: `CarType` which contains each car type. Then `WindProtector` table contains possible options for wind protectors. And finally a table which joins them and defines which combinations are possible:

```sql
create table dbo.CarType (
    car_type varchar(20) not null primary key
);

insert dbo.CarType (car_type) VALUES
('HARD_TOP'),
('CONVERTIBLE');

create table dbo.WindProtector (
     wind_protector varchar(20) not null primary key
);

insert dbo.WindProtector (wind_protector) VALUES
('NA'),
('FLAPBLAST_2'),
('FLAPBLAST_3');

create table dbo.CarOptions (
     options_id int not null primary key  -- surrogate key
  ,  car_type varchar(20) not null references CarType (car_type)
  ,  wind_protector varchar(20) not null references WindProtector (wind_protector)
  ,  unique (car_type, wind_protector)
);

insert into dbo.CarOptions (options_id, car_type, wind_protector) VALUES
(1, 'HARD_TOP', 'NA'),
(2, 'CONVERTIBLE', 'FLAPBLAST_3'),
(3, 'CONVERTIBLE', 'FLAPBLAST_2');

create table dbo.Car (
    car_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER default(newid()) 
 ,  option_id int not null references CarOptions (options_id)
);

insert dbo.Car (option_id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45b6dba82192e5eaca6ebd5c3d0fb2f1)

You may want to merge `Car` and `CarOptions` into one table, depending on requirements.

I would also recommend using `NULL` instead of `'NA'`.